# FETCH command IMAP based on headers defined by RFC822

Tags: imap, thunderbird

I have this command come from the Thunderbird client email:

```
6 UID fetch 1 (UID RFC822.SIZE FLAGS BODY.PEEK[HEADER.FIELDS (From To Cc Bcc Subject Date Message-ID Priority X-Priority References Newsgroups In-Reply-To Content-Type Reply-To)])
```

To respond to it, I am sending the following statements:

```
* 1 FETCH (UID 1 RFC822.SIZE 526 BODY[] {526}
* FLAGS (\Seen)
From: "Bob Smith" <bob@bar.com>
To: "John Smith" <john@foo.com>
Cc: "Joe Aaron" <joe@bar.com>
Subject: Sintaxe correta para criação de cabeçalhos de email
Date: 30 Jul 1996 11:54:54 -0000
Message-ID: <OTJMCQtXnqgMaP1rLJi-cD9IvuH+xuVndE-DoWAZB0cbdffqHdw@mail.gmail.com>
Reply-To: <bob@bar.com>
```

After this, the Thunderbird client does not send any commands and doesn't fetch anything more, and messages don't appear in the mailbox.

The "download message" starts and never drops in the Thunderbird client.

Comment: Maybe you should send this command to another server and see what it returns.  You're missing everything else it requested, the literal, etc.  You should start by reading RFC 3501 and send commands to other servers to see how they respond.

Comment: In RFC 3501, the RFC 822 is mentioned in this case in analogy from commands defined in RFC 3501. Do you have any suggestion of server with debug system? @Max

Comment: You could set up a server in non-SSL mode and do a packet capture, or tunnel it through a proxy that logs it, or all sorts of things.

Comment: What Max says. But I'm feeling generous tonight... you're sending a response that says 526 bytes of header fields will follow, followed by a flag update that definitely isn't a header fiield, followed by about 300 bytes of header field, followed by nothing. Thunderbird will be waiting for the rest of the 526 bytes and then the conclusion of the response, and it gets that it'll be very surprised by the flag update you include in the header.

Answer (score 0):

Did you send the " OK FETCH completed" response? You must do that to signal command completion to the client.

Check the [FETCH command](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.4.5) section in the [IMAP RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501). More specifically [page 58](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#page-58) reveals an [OK response](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-7.1.1) example.